# Not able to open web application on Amazon EC2 even if port is opened

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, django

I have a `t1.micro` instance with the public DNS that looks similar to the following:

```
ec2-184-72-67-202.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

(some numbers have been changed)

On this instance, I am running the following Django app:

```
$ sudo python manage.py runserver --settings=vlists.settings.dev
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.1, using settings 'vlists.settings.dev'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

I have opened the `port 8000` through the AWS console

[image: Screenshot]:

When I navigate to the the following URL in Chrome, I get the message: `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to`:

```
http://ec2-184-72-67-202.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Netstat:**

```
netstat -lan | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: Post the output of `netstat -lan | grep 8000`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Sounds like the server is set to respond only on the localhost.
Check your Django config, and make sure it's set to respond on all interfaces.

Update:

```
netstat -lan | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Yep, definitely an issue with your bindings. 127.0.0.1 should instead be your Public IP or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces.

Comment: Yes, that is it, I was missing this

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the runserver to all ports.. by default it just binds to localhost

```
 python manage.py runserver --settings=vlists.settings.dev 0.0.0.0:8000
```